# WinEdt to open in "Reader"

Tags: windows, viewers, winedt

My question is a mixture of WinEdt settings, Windows 10 administrator settings and Windows apps. I realize that it might not be exactly appropriate here, but I figured some people might have wanted to do this same thing.

So I want WinEdt to open the compiled pdf's in the "Reader" app of Windows 10, which comes with Windows 10 and it's available in Windows Store. I generally know how to change WinEdt settings to use a specific program for a specific reason (Options -> Execution Modes), but the problem is that you have to enter the executable's address in the box, and I cannot possibly find the directory address for the Reader app.

I did everything that I could think of, and even ended up messing up my WinEdt and had to spend an hour to fix it from the Registry. I cannot on earth find the executable for "Reader". Windows Store apps usually go in Program Files-> WindowsApps, but even there, there was no Reader.exe file. I'm drawing blanks here. Any help would be much appreciated!!

I'm running WinEdt 9.1 and Windows 10. Thanks!

Comment: Reader doesn't come in windows 10. You have to install it. And all those app exe files are inside `Program Files\WindowsApps` which is hidden and locked.

Comment: Here are some indications how to create a short cut to such an app (untested) http://www.tenforums.com/installation-setup/2135-heres-how-find-location-metro-apps-win-10-a.html

Comment: @HarishKumar as I mentioned I already checked the WindowsApps folder and could not find an executable file.
I believe it did come with my Windows 10, because I haven't downloaded it myself.

Comment: No it doesn't come with windows 10. You have to get it from windows store. It is free,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about program availability in Windows.